# erro na função isempty

Tags: matlab

Tenho um erro nesta função `isempty` no matlab, necessito que quando se encontre vazia através de uma matriz faça a condição a seguir ao `if isempty`:

```
function bn_hat = my_descodificador_Hamming_v2(rn,N,H_Ham,n_cyc,k_cyc,simb_alfa)

rn      = reshape(rn,n_cyc,N/k_cyc)';

bn_til      = rem(rn*H_Ham',2);

sn_til      = bi2de(bn_til,'right-msb')';
cn_hat      = rn';
pos         = find(sn_til>0);
pos_erro    = nansum(simb_alfa(sn_til(pos)),1);

if isempty(pos_erro,[])

    cn_hat(pos_erro+n_cyc*(pos-1)) =  not( cn_hat(pos_erro+n_cyc) );

end

bn_hat      = cn_hat(k_cyc:end,:)';
bn_hat      = reshape(bn_hat',1,[]);
```

o erro que me dá é o seguinte:

> Eb/No = +0 dB  :: erros = Error using isempty
>   Too many input arguments.
>
> Error in my_descodificador_Hamming_v2 (line 11)
>   if isempty(pos_erro,[])
>
> Error in sim_FSK_incoerente (line 56)
>   bn_hat = my_descodificador_Hamming_v2(cn_hat,N,H_Ham,n_cyc,k_cyc,simb_alfa);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A funcão `isempty` aceita apenas um parâmetro, mas no seu código tem dois.

Se você usar

```
if isempty(pos_erro)
```

deve resolver.

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado pela ajuda.